# Why is my android app using so much memory at startup

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have been looking into a memory leak issue for a while.

I found a cover flow on the internet from http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html

Now I was under the impression this app was causing my outofmemory issues, and its still possible that it has something to do with it. However, I have deleted everything from my application except the splash screen. There are no other activities. and it does Nothing......

The initial intent loads the Splash Screen activity.

My application is using between 79 and 83 percent of my available heap. The phone has given me 2.816M and i have apparently allocated 2.278M this last run.

First off, 3M of available space to run an app seems like not a lot. However 2.2M loaded into memory at initial boot seems like a ton of memory consumed when the only thing I am doing is loading a single activity with an imageview pointed to an icon resource measured at around 4k......

How/Why is my app using so much memory for nothing, and how can I alleviate my 80% memory consumption at boot.

I am developing on a T-Mobile G2 and I have nothing running except this app and the default services that run on a droid.

here is some of my memory dump info

suspect 1

```
2,239 instances of "java.lang.Class", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 673,760 (35.83%) bytes.

Biggest instances:

class com.ibm.icu4jni.util.Resources$DefaultTimeZones @ 0x401dc878 - 166,600 (8.86%) bytes.
class android.text.Html$HtmlParser @ 0x4010de58 - 126,592 (6.73%) bytes.
class org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services @ 0x4007fd98 - 51,456 (2.74%) bytes.
class android.content.res.Resources @ 0x4004bb78 - 38,768 (2.06%) bytes.
class com.abc.AppData @ 0x44d1e040 - 26,872 (1.43%) bytes.


Keywords
java.lang.Class
```

suspect 2

```
7,072 instances of "java.lang.String", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 435,560 (23.16%) bytes. 

Keywords
java.lang.String
```

suspect 3

```
58 instances of "org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 289,288 (15.38%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.Hashtable$HashtableEntry[]", loaded by "<system class loader>"

Keywords
org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject
java.util.Hashtable$HashtableEntry[]
```

as you can see the system appears to be loading up and using all of the memory I have been given. How can I get it to give me more memory. 3 megs is not very much to work with. and I am trying to show an image gallery.

Comment: Bear in mind that although the image may be 4k on disk, it's *compressed* on disk (presumably). I'm not keen on the exact internals of Android, but the renderer most probably decompresses the image in memory.

Comment: but for a 4k image to decompress and use 2.2 megs... that sounds a little like overkill....

Comment: That would be fairly extreme, yes, but I did want to note that it's almost certainly taking up more than 4k of memory. What's the resolution and bit depth of the image? You can multiply it out and you'll know approximately how much space in memory it would take up when uncompressed. Then at least you can account for some of it.

Comment: I did you one better. I removed it. and it is relatively the same size. How much of the heap is taken up by other developers apps. Is this app just a Fluke or is the application supposed to only give me about 700k of available space on my heap ?

Comment: I'm not sure. It does seem like a very small amount of heap space. It definitely sounds like the VM is doing something really funky...

Comment: And here I am in 2017 worrying that my app is taking up more than 64 Megs of RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into memory leaks in the past but not with android. In the past I used the eclipse memory analyzer tool (second link) which I found very useful.  To use it you need to generate a heap dump file (or memory snapshot), the blog post tells you how to do this (first link).

http://www.andorfi.net/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android-applications/

http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: I tried doing the memory dump. but eclipse took over the file without letting me convert it. Just opened it right up. and told me that 1.3megs of my dump was not understandable.

Comment: Did you try using the DDMS to open the heap dump file? What other methods have you tried?

Comment: I did finally git a good heap dump. I have to close eclipse, and dump from /android-sdk/tools/ddms and then convert it, and I can see more in eclipse

Comment: I guess it does not matter weather i use DDMS in eclipse or on a stand alone. it shows the same 1.3m remainder... what does it mean by Remainder.

Comment: Also, from past experiance, it is better to generate the heap dump file when the out of memory error is thrown.  If you run your application with the VM flag -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError a heap dump is written on the first Out Of Memory Error.  I have not tried this with Android so I am not sure if this will work.  If this works, it will be very easy to pin point which objects are causing the problem.

Comment: My question here is why is the application consuming all the memory it is allocating to me. and how to allocate more.

Comment: Have you tried running this application on the VM or on a different phone?  You could also try resetting your current development phone back to factory defaults.

Comment: well it seems that getting rid of my memory leak. However small did keep my application running. However I still only have 3 megs of memory to play with. At least the application is still working. I just wish I had more room. I mean.... for the app to take 80% of my memory before I even load seems ludicrous.

Answer (score 0):

Debug and logging tips may help offer some insight.

https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html

Comment: I am debugging and checking logs. The error I was given was an out of memory exception. And that is what got me into investigating the memory. However I deleted everything in my application except the splash screen. and when the app hit onCreate in the splash screen i stopped it at a breakpoint. The application gave me under 3 megs, and was arleady using 80% of that. I had not executed a single line of code.

Comment: i do like the logcat app. i didnt know that was available.. thanks for that.